# Will an entangled photon bouncing off a/penetrating through a mirror "de-tangle" it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement, reflection, quantum-optics

Lets say I create a pair of entangled photons. I then shoot one of the photons through a semi-silvered(semi-reflecting) mirror. one(or both) of the photons are reflected, and (or) one (or both) of the photons penetrate/pass through the mirror. will either one of or both of the actions/interactions detangle the photons in question? (see image for details)
[image]

Comment: If you can resolve the change in state (position, momentum) of the mirror, then yes, but this is highly impractical in most scenarios

Comment: @QuantumMechanic so more likely the photons will remain entangled?

Comment: Yes. See some of the related questions, they're pretty intriguing. Also, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94416/291677