# Why does the imparting of momentum to a mirror not count as "observation" in Wheeler's delayed choice experiment?

Tags: optics, quantum-interpretations

Presumably light pressure would change the momentum of the beam-splitting mirrors in the interferometer version of [Wheeler's delayed choice experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed-choice_experiment).  And it's not until the photon encounters the detector at the end that we consider it "observed", and presumably the probability field has collapsed (excuse my pop-science misunderstandings of the concept).  But why does the photon's encounter with the splitter not count as a measurable, field-collapsing "observation", resulting in the photon either passing through or being reflected, instead of remaining as a probability and later interfering with itself?

Comment: Nice question! Here are some related ones: [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282410/why-can-interaction-with-a-macroscopic-apparatus-such-as-a-stern-gerlach-machin), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460855/why-arent-particles-constantly-measured-by-the-whole-universe?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94416/why-doesnt-a-typical-beam-splitter-cause-a-photon-to-decohere?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: So, @knzhou, based on some of the answers in #3, is it basically because the initial momentum of a macroscopic object like a mirror can never be known ahead of time, such that we cannot determine the momentum of the photon that caused the change?  And, by extension, does it mean that momentum-changing events are never sufficient to qualify as observation, whereas state-changing events (like the chirality of a photochemical) are observations?

Comment: First sentence -- yes, that's absolutely right! Second sentence -- no, the principle is just that observation requires a _substantial_ change in state. For example, if a stray air molecule bounces off an electron (thereby changing the molecule's momentum significantly), that counts as an observation. But bouncing off macroscopic objects doesn't because the momentum uncertainty of a macroscopic object is much higher.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119743/qm-why-is-reflection-of-a-photon-not-a-measurement/119749#119749